# Keeping file offsets while parsing HTML with the DOM?

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

I want to modify `<img src="">` attributes in not-too-malformed HTML (WordPress posts). I know I can take the simple way and use regexes, but I'm afraid [people in blue furry suits will come haunt me in my sleep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67008/are-rumors-of-a-film-true-i-hope-so-by-golly/67041#67041).

If I use the DOM parser to read the HTML and modify the `<img>` tags, I'm afraid I can't reconstruct the post exactly as it was (with only my modification), because the DOM parser will probably do too much cleanup and maybe remove essential data. A SAX parser can probably not handle invalid XML, so this will also not work.

So, is there a middle way, where I can use a DOM parser, but one that knows where each element started, so I can do string replacements or something similar from there? I know some nodes in the DOM tree will not exist in the source document (`<b>Some <i>bizarre</b> formatting</i>` will probably trigger this), but does this mean it is always impossible? I see there is a [`DOMNode::getLineNo()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.getlineno.php) added in PHP 5.3, but I'm using 5.2.x.

Answer (score 0):

If PHP's DOM will write "too clean" results, you *could* try string-based [SimpleHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) whether it's more lenient.

However, with formatting as bizarre as you show, I would never entirely trust the parser to do it "right". But try it out, maybe it just skips such stuff.

The DOM library's `DOMNode` class has a [`getLineNo()`](http://php.net/manual/de/domnode.getlineno.php) method. I don't entirely see how this works though, seeing as it doesn't provide an offset to go with it. Not sure whether that'll help your use case.

Comment: My formatting example was theoretical, why this cannot work for all DOM nodes. I believe that the WordPress editor cleans it up, so I won't have to handle such a case. And the `DOMNode::getLineNo()` function could be useful to reduce the scope of the final string replace, but since I'm on PHP 5.2 I can't use it.