# How to use PHP's DOMDocument to alter only certain parts of a HTML Document?

Tags: php, html, dom, html-parsing

Suppose I have a string `$str` representing a HTML document. It contains a substring `$substr` describing some HTML DOM Node. I do not know or can easily match the `$substr`, I only know what DOM Node I am looking for.

I ultimately want to replace this substring by another string `$replacement`.

I know how to find and extract the DOM Node using PHP's DOMDocument and Xpath,...
But simply altering the DOMDocument and then using `saveHTML` or `saveXML` has the following problems:

- It will not only change `$substr` (it will produce valid HTML or XML, which might significantly differ from the input string)
- There are severe restrictions on `$replacement`: It has to parseable as (X)HTML/XML. But suppose I want to have `$replacement = "<<<<<<<<"`?

There are some sub problems that might help:

- Is there a way to get the starting and ending position in the `$str` for a a certain DOM Node? (Similar to the ::getLineNo method)? 
  This question was asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155255/keeping-file-offsets-while-parsing-html-with-the-dom)
- Is it possible to dump a concatenation of the raws strings that a DOMDocument had as input?
- Do you see a simpler or better solution?

Comment: If you can exactly match the substring with `str_replace`, do so and call it a day. I wouldn't consider that a bad solution. Bad solutions involve replacing at the string level when you *cannot* match exactly (i.e. with regexes).

Comment: This is no option. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: It'll have to be a RegExp then as you're treating a markup document as a string. Porting it into DOMDocument parses it to an XML/HTML object so you'll not be manipulating the original string. This is the kind of thing that RegExps (and Perl I suppose) are pretty much designed to deal with.

Comment: But the parser DOES know where the substring starts and ends that lead to a certain node! (He already allows to retrieve the line number!)

Comment: @JohannesGerer: Not necessarily. If the input is treated as a stream and parsed incrementally then the parser has no reason to keep start/end offsets for each node.

Comment: @Jon: A Reason? If someone needs this information and the parser can easily record it, I think thats reason enough.

Comment: @JohannesGerer - It not as easy as you'd think to keep track of the original source in such a way as to bind that source to the DOM nodes. DOM nodes can get created in odd ways by the parser and the order of nodes in the DOM is not always the same as the order of the characters in input source. If you tried to serialize a mixture of original source and DOM node content, there would almost certainly be some indeterminate states.

Comment: @Alohci: Ok, but what about the getLineNo()?

Comment: @JohannesGerer - that's a somewhat easier parsing problem. The tokeniser increments a line number count every time it sees a new line character/character-pair, and the node constructor asks the tokeniser for the current line number whenever it creates a node, and attaches that value to the node.

Comment: @Alohci: Ok, so the following should be possible: "The tokeniser increments a character count every time it sees a character".

Comment: That gets you the starting and ending positions but doesn't solve the serialization problems. Consider this fragment: `<b>1<i>2<s>3</b>4</i>5</s>`. This parses to 6 elements: 1 `b`, 2 `i`s and 3 `s`s. The start and end positions for the second `i` and second `s` are identical (after character positions 16 and 21 respectively). Somehow you have manage the correctly ordered serialisation of that, correctly discarding all the fabricated tags on the way.

Comment: It would still be possible and good for my original problem to get the position of the "i" and "/i" characters that were responsible for the 2 `<i>` to form.

Comment: @JohannesGerer: The point is that this cannot *always* work. That it can work for a subset of possible inputs is not reason enough to implement it, it would simply not be worth the trouble supporting the feature.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/ have you tried this ? its much better library to handle things like this.